# How can I organize portable applications with a customizable launcher menu?

Tags: windows-7, portable-apps

I have acquired quite a few useful tools that do various things and do not require installation (e.g. putty, ftp wanderer... etc). Some of them come as a single file while others need a folder to themselves.

I need to have them all in one place and organize them with a single custom menu. I'd like to customize the location of the various programs and display the names and the icons in the menu.

How can I do it? I am using windows 7.

Comment: Which OS? And why not just use that OS to make a folder full of shortcuts/links to the various programs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a Windows system, the [PortapleApps.com](http://portableapps.com/) launcher should do the job.
Altough its primary use is to provide a launcher for apps downloaded from the site, you can [easily add your own portable applications](http://portableapps.com/support/portable_apps_suite#addingotherapps) and place them in the menu.

[image]

---

There is also LiberKey, but I haven't used it extensively so I don't know if and how it supports custom applicatons; anyway I suppose that the usage and features of these portable suites are pretty much the same. Just try them and see which one better suit your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Codyssey CodySafe Menu](http://www.codyssey.com/) is another alternative portable applications launcher, that can be used with Windows and launched from a USB drive. It will rank your portable apps according to the frequency of usage. The more you launch them, the higher they are in the menu.

[image]

Available as both a free and Pro version, as the portable apps are in paf format, not only can you download apps from Codyssey (Pro version), you can go to [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/) and download hundreds of apps from there as well. Use them on any Windows computer, all conveniently packaged onto your usb stick.